# dynamic subject line extraction

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, data-views

We sent an email which has a dynamic subject line using Ampscript logic. is there a way to find out how may people opened subject line A vS subject line b?

when checking the job table it just shows the AMPScript in the data extract.

Comment: If you have a sendlog you can see the processed subject. Otherwise, you would need to create your own logging system if you do not have an existing flag.  E.g. using impression regions or an AMPscript upsert inside the email, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You would use a query to supply the same logic for the subscribers to see what subject line they received and then link that to opens. No data view captures the dynamic values at send time. For future sends you could evaluate using a sendlog if you don't have a way to identify today what values they had at send time

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [A/B testing functionality](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_abtest_configure.htm&type=5) to compare both email versions based on the Highest unique open rate: Version with the highest unique open rate.

Comment: A/B subject line wasn't used, the developer used ampscript to drive the logic

Answer (score 0):

I believe enabling a sendlog would work provided you have that same field in the log and email.
Basically you have an AMPScript variable for your subject.

%%[
var @subject
set @subject = "whatever your subject is"
]%%
Then you would write %%=v(@subject)=%%

In your Send Log DE, you can create a column saying "subject" which should pull the populated values for a given user

Comment: It's my understanding that in order for an attribute to show in SendLog (i.e. "Subject") that attribute must be included in the sending DE as an attribute. Or so I thought. Am I incorrect here?